# What is cross domain request / cross domain attacks / cross domain protocols

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can some body explain what is cross domain request / cross domain attacks / cross domain protocols with respect the ajax terminology.

Comment: Try Wikipedia, the basics are all there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cross domain request: Requesting content from another host, than where the website is hosted. For example site hosted at google loads a facebook icon from facebook domain.

Cross domain attack: I think there are whole books about these, but basically: The domain making the request cannot verify the content retrieved from another host, so it can be modified. Other usual is sending a login form or some other form from another domain instead of the actual login page. Badly designed interface could let you log in or retrieve sensitive data.

I'm not sure about Ajax protocols.

Comment: These answers are freely formed and not from any actual source. Just from my own head. Don't use them for any actual reference.